# openapi3: how to specify that an object schema should be a schema itself?

Tags: openapi

I want a field in a PUT body that is itself supposed to be a jsonschema. How do I formally specify this rather than putting that info in a description?

```
  type: object
  description: "..."
  properties:
    foo:
      type: integer
    create_schema:
      type: object
      description: >
        jsonschema (following http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema) of the CREATE payload...
```

OpenAPI doesn't like the schema keyword in a definition here